# Play audio and get current second of playback using Python?

Tags: python, pyaudio, sox

I am working on speech interface with python. I am having trouble with audio playback.

What do you use to black back simple mp3 files on the raspberry pi?

I need to play audio and 2 seconds before the end of the playback I need to start another task (opening the stream of the microphone)
How can I archive this? May problem is that I haven't found a way to read the current seconds of the playback yet. If I could read this, I would just start a new thread when the currenttime is audiolength - 2 seconds.

I hope you can help me or have any experience with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this. 
PyAudio is providing a way to play audio chunk by chunk. Through that you can read the current chunk and compare it to the overall size of the audio.

```py
class AudioPlayer():
    """AudioPlayer class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.chunk = 1024
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._running = True


    def play(self, audiopath):
        self._running = True
        #storing how much we have read already
        self.chunktotal = 0
        wf = wave.open(audiopath, 'rb')
        stream = self.audio.open(format =self.audio.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),channels = wf.getnchannels(),rate = wf.getframerate(),output = True)
        print(wf.getframerate())
        # read data (based on the chunk size)
        data = wf.readframes(self.chunk)
        #THIS IS THE TOTAL LENGTH OF THE AUDIO
        audiolength = wf.getnframes() / float(wf.getframerate())

        while self._running:
            if data != '':
                stream.write(data)
                self.chunktotal = self.chunktotal + self.chunk
                #calculating the percentage
                percentage = (self.chunktotal/wf.getnframes())*100
                #calculating the current seconds
                current_seconds = self.chunktotal/float(wf.getframerate())
                data = wf.readframes(self.chunk)

            if data == b'':
                break

        # cleanup stream
        stream.close()

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False
```

Hope it helps someone,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

Try [just_playback](https://github.com/cheofusi/just_playback). It's a wrapper I wrote around miniaudio that provides playback control functionality like pausing, resuming, seeking, getting the current playback positions and setting the playback volume.

Comment: Top work top man! I've been through 5 sound libraries and this one finally meets my needs.